Would it be possible to have "Atlantis" right westward from the Strait of Gibraltar, and have the Mediterrean remain the same?
Im imagining an Alternate History with a realistic Atlantis.
In my setting, the world is largely identical to our own, physically, if not historically, but with one major exception:
The Azores, Canary Islands, Madera and several other smaller islands along the Spanish and West African coast do not exist. Instead, their landmass is roughly combined into a 25 000 km2 island sitting west from the Straits of Gibraltar.
The island is crescent shaped (with a giant natural port facing Gibraltar) and sits roughly in equal distance from our world's Gibraltar, Casablanca and Faro. It effectively covers about a 1/3 of the funnel that allows the Atlantic to reach the Strait.
Question: is it possible for such island to exist, and yet have the Mediterranean have the same properties as in our timeline? Or would the partial "dam" it created somehow change the sea? (like having a different sea level, more/less salty, vastly different climate, etc)
What Im essentially asking, would it be possible to have such Atlantis AND the climate/sea conditions that Mediterranean civilizations grew on remain the same?
If not, how far must the Atlantis be moved westward from the Strait to not cause problems? (ideally, I want it in a distance that would be realistic for even a Neolithic culture to cross relatively safely, not push it into the middle of Atlantic).
Im open to the idea of redesigning the shape of Atlantis, if it were to help, or even make it a compact archipelago, but would prefer for it to remain one landmass with a big bay on the eastern end.
Im also ok with leaving Azores. Canary Islands and Madera alone, and just creating Atlantis ex-nihilo, if these islands are somehow fundamental to how ocean currents work, or something.

If you would add a map showing how you envision your geography it would be a great help

Adding any large landmass will change the climate of anywhere now sheltered from the prevailing wind

The undersea topography matters as well. Reducing the deep cold Atlantic currents into the Mediterranean basin will change the temperature and salinity of the Mediterranean.

An island the size of Sicily (25,662km²) in this location looks cool on the map and will not greatly alter the ocean currents and geography of the Mediterranean Sea as a whole, but it will certainly have some influence on the climate of southern Spain and northern Morocco. The impact is difficult to predict accurately, but the blocking of humid coastal winds is expected to make the region more arid than it is on Earth.
Just don't make the channel between the island and the mainland too narrow, as this could affect the salinity of the internal sea, but what you propose doesn't seem to be a problem.
And as a personal suggestion, unless it is important in your plot, I don't think it's necessary to remove the other islands mentioned as they are quite far away and at least geographically they wouldn't affect your Atlantis that much. More islands are more tales to tell.

Feels like this would really reduce circulation in an already narrow channel, why isn't that the case?

I had a silly notion that removing some of the nearby Atlantic islands would "balance out" the addition of Atlantis, but If this is not necessary I can skip this idea.
Would the elevation of Atlantis matter? For example, if the island was fairly low (no mountains or high cliffs etc) would it reduce the effect on the weather?

Every detail matters, but not that much. It would be necessary to carry out a detailed scientific study to accurately predict the impacts on the climate, but no one will bother doing it. That being said, the higher the mountains the higher the impact, but a flat island would be strange. The best scenario would be mild hills.
